# What does $N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$ mean in van Lint's stating of Ramsey's Theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I've started reading van Lint and Wilson's *A Course in Combinatorics* and on Theorem 3.3 (Ramsey's Theorem) they use the notation $N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$ without an explanation prior to it. Can someone explain what this meant? I would also appreciate an explanation on what the $q_i$'s and the $r$ referred to in $N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$. Below is how the theorem was stated.

Theorem 3.3. Let $r \ge 1$ and $q_i \ge r, i = 1,2,...,s$ be given. There exists a minimal positive integer $N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$ with the following property. Let $S$ be a set with n elements. Suppose that all $n \choose{r}$ $r$-subsets of $S$ are divided into $s$ mutually exclusive families $T_1,T_2,...,T_s$ ("colors"). Then if $n \ge N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$ there is an $i, 1\le i \le s$, and some $q_i$-subset of $S$ for which every $r$-subset is in $T_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem in fact gives the definition of $N(q_1, q_2, ... , q_s ; r)$!  It is just the number whose existence is guaranteed by the theorem.

To amplify: I expect you have seen the following as it is probably the simplest question in Ramsey theory.

> Show that if the edges of the complete graph on $6$ vertices are coloured red or blue in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a red triangle or a blue triangle.

We can rephrase this as a "problem to find" rather than a "problem to prove".

> Find the smallest $n$ with the following property: if the edges of $K_n$ are coloured red or blue in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a red triangle or a blue triangle.

The answer is of course $n=6$, and we express this by the equation $N(3,3;2)=6$.

This can be generalised in a number of ways.  We could ask:

> Find the smallest $n$ with the following property: if the edges of $K_n$ are coloured red or blue in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a $K_3$ with all edges red or a $K_5$ with all edges blue.

The least such $n$ is denoted $N(3,5;2)$; in fact it is known that $N(3,5;2)=14$.  Next, suppose that we have three colours: for example,

> $N(5,6,7;2)$ is the smallest $n$ with the following property: if the edges of $K_n$ are coloured red, blue or green in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a $K_5$ with all edges red or a $K_6$ with all edges blue or a $K_7$ with all edges green.

The parameter $2$ at the end of all these $N$s can also be generalised, though the concept is rather more difficult to grasp.  The reason we have written a $2$ so far is that an edge of a graph can be identified with a $2$-element subset of its vertices.  So our basic Ramsey theory question can be expressed as

> Show that if the $2$-element subsets of a $6$-element set are coloured red or blue in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a $3$-element subset in which every $2$-element subset is red or a $3$-element subset in which every $2$-element subset is blue.

Think about this carefully until you can see that it is really nothing more than a different way of writing the first problem.  Our most recent example would be

> $N(5,6,7;2)$ is the smallest $n$ with the following property: if the $2$-element subsets of an $n$-element set are coloured red, blue or green in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a $5$-element subset in which every $2$-element subset is red or a $6$-element subset in which every $2$-element subset is blue or a $7$-element subset in which every $2$-element subset is green.

And then we can consider, say, $4$-element subsets instead of $2$-element subsets.

> $N(5,6,7;4)$ is the smallest $n$ with the following property: if the $4$-element subsets of an $n$-element set are coloured red, blue or green in any way whatsoever, there will always be either a $5$-element subset in which every $4$-element subset is red or a $6$-element subset in which every $4$-element subset is blue or a $7$-element subset in which every $4$-element subset is green.

Since the "colouring" analogy is now rather hard to visualise - note that it is the **set** that is coloured, not the elements of the set - we tend to speak of "dividing $r$-element subsets into mutually exclusive families", and this gives the statement of the theorem.

It **is** hard to get your head around all this logic but take it easy, starting with the simplest examples, and see how you go.